# Is there a way to create a HTML extension method to create a cache busting static file path?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using .netcore 3.1 and c# for my project.

I created a Helper class that generates a hash of a file and adds it to the end of the file path in the view.

For example:
Send the in the "/global.js" path, then gets that file to hash it. Then returns the path as "/global.js?v={hash}".

This is done by sending the following objects through to the BaseController and initialising the helper class and setting as a ViewBag to be used within the _Layout.cshtml:

- IDistributedCache cache
- ActionContext actionContext

Helper Class:

```
public CacheContentTagHelper(IDistributedCache cache, ActionContext actionContext, string contentRootPath)
    {
        this.contentRootPath = contentRootPath;
        this.cache = cache;

        // use the IFileProvider configured for the Static Files middleware
        this.fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(contentRootPath);
        this.urlHelper = new UrlHelper(actionContext);
    }

    public string GetUrl(string filePath)
    {
        string path = filePath;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            IFileInfo file = fileProvider.GetFileInfo(urlHelper.Content($"~/wwwroot{path}"));

            if (file?.Exists == true && !file.IsDirectory && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file.PhysicalPath))
            {
                string hash = Task.Run(() => GetFileHashAsync(file)).Result;
                path = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hash)
                    ? $"{path}?v={hash}"
                    : path;
            }
        }

        return path;
    }
```

And then I do the following in the view to run that method:

```
@{ 
    CacheContentTagHelper test = (CacheContentTagHelper)ViewBag.CacheContentTagHelper;
<script>
    $LAB.setGlobalDefaults({ Debug: false, AllowDuplicates: false })
        .script("/resources/js/plugins/jquery-3.4.1.min.js").wait(function () {
        window.lazySizesConfig = window.lazySizesConfig || {};
        lazySizesConfig.loadMode = 1;
        lazySizesConfig.expand = 0;
    })
        .script("https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default%2CArray.prototype.find%2CIntersectionObserver")
        .script("/resources/js/plugins/barba.umd.min.js")
        .script("/resources/js/plugins/lazysizes.min.js")
        .script("/resources/js/plugins/picturefill.min.js")
        .script("/resources/js/plugins/focus-visible.min.js")
        .script("/resources/js/plugins/gsap.min.js")
        .script("/resources/js/plugins/ScrollTrigger.min.js").wait()
        .script("@test.GetUrl("/resources/js/global.min.js")").wait(function () {
        BEGlobal.Init();
        FEGlobal.Init();
</script>
}
```

But, I would like to be able to do `.script("@this.GetUrl("/resources/js/global.min.js")").wait(function () {`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to modify your code as follows (single quotes outside and double quotes inside):  `.script('@this.GetUrl("/resources/js/global.min.js")').wait(function (){}`, Or you can define a variable to store the returned path first, then assign to the script() method, like this:`@{ CacheContentTagHelper test = (CacheContentTagHelper)ViewBag.CacheContentTagHelper; var path = test.GetUrl("/resources/js/global.min.js"); <script> ...  .script("@path").wait()</script>}`